pytest anyio - create a mongodb motor fixture that lasts throughout session
I want to create a mongodb session with motor that will start and end with the tests with pytest and the anyio pytest plugin. But after tests are run, the entries persist in the database.
# db.py
mongo_client = AsyncIOMotorClient('conn url')

# conftest.py
from .db import mongo_client

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def anyio_backend() -> str:
    return 'asyncio'

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
async def mongo_session(anyio_backend) -> AsyncGenerator[None, None]:
    async with await mongo_client.start_session() as session:
        session.start_transaction()
        yield
        await session.abort_transaction()

# test_mongo.py
from .db import mongo_client

async def test_add_item() -> None:
    # add item into db from mongo_cilent

I expected to see no entries in the database after running tests, but I see entries. Meaning this fixture was not called.

Why not utilize pytest-mongo? https://github.com/mdomke/pytest-mongodb

@TeejayBruno While I did discover an async version, I wanted to try to test on a real DB instead of mocking it out. I have gone with that option but I still am keeping the question open to know.
